# cgroup file in a created group seemingly disappears after a day (including suspend)

Tags: cgroups

I've started using `cgoups` (`cgreate -g cpu:gr1` / `cgset -r cpu.max` / `cgexec`) regularly recently. More than once I've noticed I create cgroup and run a command as above, then after a day or two (of other work with linux system not restarted, however could be suspended and resumed), want to repeat the same command, but "cgroup change of group failed" and I see in `/sys/fs` that group does not have file named `cpu.max`. Web search had not found anything similar. What could be the cause? How to investigate? TIA

Interestingly today after I observed the issue, I've added another cgroup (`cgreate` / `cgset cpu.max`) and I've seen the problematic group also having `cpu.max` and the original command works again.

I recall I'm able to run the command several times in a day, it is that when I try to run it next day (about that duration) and maybe only after suspend (but I'm not sure) I often observe the issue.